# How can i combine ApexCharts Candlestick chart with multiple lines in the same chart

Tags: apexcharts

I want to add multiple lines to ApexCharts candlestick chart. The lines have different lengths. How can i do this? (I develop in another language than java (LiveCode) but want to use ApexCharts for showing stock charts with resistance and trend lines in the Browser Widget).

Tried to copy line chart script in the candle chart but i could not get the lines to show in the candlestick chart. Below the original candlestick chart script is shown that occupies the html page (basic.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>CandleStick Chart</title>


  <link href="../../assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <style>
    #chart {
      max-width: 650px;
      margin: 35px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart">

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>
  <script src="../../assets/ohlc.js"></script>

  <script>
    var options = {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'candlestick',
      },
      series: [{
        data: [{
            x: new Date(1538778600000),
            y: [6629.81, 6650.5, 6623.04, 6633.33]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538780400000),
            y: [6632.01, 6643.59, 6620, 6630.11]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538782200000),
            y: [6630.71, 6648.95, 6623.34, 6635.65]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538784000000),
            y: [6635.65, 6651, 6629.67, 6638.24]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538785800000),
            y: [6638.24, 6640, 6620, 6624.47]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538787600000),
            y: [6624.53, 6636.03, 6621.68, 6624.31]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538789400000),
            y: [6624.61, 6632.2, 6617, 6626.02]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538791200000),
            y: [6627, 6627.62, 6584.22, 6603.02]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538793000000),
            y: [6605, 6608.03, 6598.95, 6604.01]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538794800000),
            y: [6604.5, 6614.4, 6602.26, 6608.02]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538796600000),
            y: [6608.02, 6610.68, 6601.99, 6608.91]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538798400000),
            y: [6608.91, 6618.99, 6608.01, 6612]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538800200000),
            y: [6612, 6615.13, 6605.09, 6612]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538802000000),
            y: [6612, 6624.12, 6608.43, 6622.95]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538803800000),
            y: [6623.91, 6623.91, 6615, 6615.67]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538805600000),
            y: [6618.69, 6618.74, 6610, 6610.4]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538807400000),
            y: [6611, 6622.78, 6610.4, 6614.9]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538809200000),
            y: [6614.9, 6626.2, 6613.33, 6623.45]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538811000000),
            y: [6623.48, 6627, 6618.38, 6620.35]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538812800000),
            y: [6619.43, 6620.35, 6610.05, 6615.53]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538814600000),
            y: [6615.53, 6617.93, 6610, 6615.19]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538816400000),
            y: [6615.19, 6621.6, 6608.2, 6620]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538818200000),
            y: [6619.54, 6625.17, 6614.15, 6620]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538820000000),
            y: [6620.33, 6634.15, 6617.24, 6624.61]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538821800000),
            y: [6625.95, 6626, 6611.66, 6617.58]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538823600000),
            y: [6619, 6625.97, 6595.27, 6598.86]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538825400000),
            y: [6598.86, 6598.88, 6570, 6587.16]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538827200000),
            y: [6588.86, 6600, 6580, 6593.4]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538829000000),
            y: [6593.99, 6598.89, 6585, 6587.81]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538830800000),
            y: [6587.81, 6592.73, 6567.14, 6578]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538832600000),
            y: [6578.35, 6581.72, 6567.39, 6579]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538834400000),
            y: [6579.38, 6580.92, 6566.77, 6575.96]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538836200000),
            y: [6575.96, 6589, 6571.77, 6588.92]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538838000000),
            y: [6588.92, 6594, 6577.55, 6589.22]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538839800000),
            y: [6589.3, 6598.89, 6589.1, 6596.08]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538841600000),
            y: [6597.5, 6600, 6588.39, 6596.25]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538843400000),
            y: [6598.03, 6600, 6588.73, 6595.97]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538845200000),
            y: [6595.97, 6602.01, 6588.17, 6602]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538847000000),
            y: [6602, 6607, 6596.51, 6599.95]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538848800000),
            y: [6600.63, 6601.21, 6590.39, 6591.02]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538850600000),
            y: [6591.02, 6603.08, 6591, 6591]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538852400000),
            y: [6591, 6601.32, 6585, 6592]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538854200000),
            y: [6593.13, 6596.01, 6590, 6593.34]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538856000000),
            y: [6593.34, 6604.76, 6582.63, 6593.86]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538857800000),
            y: [6593.86, 6604.28, 6586.57, 6600.01]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538859600000),
            y: [6601.81, 6603.21, 6592.78, 6596.25]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538861400000),
            y: [6596.25, 6604.2, 6590, 6602.99]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538863200000),
            y: [6602.99, 6606, 6584.99, 6587.81]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538865000000),
            y: [6587.81, 6595, 6583.27, 6591.96]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538866800000),
            y: [6591.97, 6596.07, 6585, 6588.39]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538868600000),
            y: [6587.6, 6598.21, 6587.6, 6594.27]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538870400000),
            y: [6596.44, 6601, 6590, 6596.55]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538872200000),
            y: [6598.91, 6605, 6596.61, 6600.02]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538874000000),
            y: [6600.55, 6605, 6589.14, 6593.01]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538875800000),
            y: [6593.15, 6605, 6592, 6603.06]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538877600000),
            y: [6603.07, 6604.5, 6599.09, 6603.89]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538879400000),
            y: [6604.44, 6604.44, 6600, 6603.5]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538881200000),
            y: [6603.5, 6603.99, 6597.5, 6603.86]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538883000000),
            y: [6603.85, 6605, 6600, 6604.07]
          },
          {
            x: new Date(1538884800000),
            y: [6604.98, 6606, 6604.07, 6606]
          },
        ]
      }],
      title: {
        text: 'CandleStick Chart',
        align: 'left'
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },
      yaxis: {
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
    // -------------------------
    var chart = new ApexCharts(
      document.querySelector("#chart"),
      options
    );

    chart.render();
    //--------------------------

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

n.a.

Comment: Why don't you use LiveCode's polygon tool to create the graphs?

Comment: Tried to start with the livecode polygon tool but ApexCharts could save me a lot of time and effort and it works very wel with the LC Browser Widget. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

With **apexcharts v3.20.1** and above, you can render a [Candlestick chart together with line charts](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/candlestick-charts/candlestick-with-line/).

You will need to declare a data series with two data sets:

```
const lineData = [
  {
    x: new Date(1538778600000),
    y: 6604,
  }, {
    x: new Date(1538782200000),
    y: 6602,
  },
];

const ohlcData = [
  {
    x: new Date(1538778600000),
    y: [6629.81, 6650.5, 6623.04, 6633.33],
  },
  {
    x: new Date(1538780400000),
    y: [6632.01, 6643.59, 6620, 6630.11],
  },
];

const series: ApexAxisChartSeries = [{
  name: 'line',
  type: 'line',
  data: lineData,
}, {
  name: 'candle',
  type: 'candlestick',
  data: ohlcData,
}];
```

Later on, you can then use it on your `Chart` component:

```
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts';

Chart options={chartOptions} series={series} type='candlestick' height={320} />
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v3.8.6, this is not possible, but it is in the development roadmap.

Already suggested in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/883)

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s). Saves me a lot of additional time. I be monitoring the developemnt of ApexCharts ..